# What is a Logging Facade?

Tags: logging, slf4j

I recently had a task in which i had to use SLF4J and i am writting a Journal of sorts in which i document the things i learn about.
I am also trying to describe what SLF4J is, but i keep running into the Term **"Logging Facade"**.

I have already googled some Terms like:

- what is a logging facade
- logging facade
- what is logging facade

The first Sentence on this [Page](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=slf) makes some sense but im not sure that it is the true definition of a "Logging Facade".

**Could anyone please elaborate what a Logging Facade is and what it exactly does?**

Comment: [Check the Wikipedia page for the facade pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).  "Facade" here just refers to the design pattern being used.  Basically, `slf4j` is a facade for a single logging interface, behind which there might be many different logging frameworks (e.g. `log4j`, `Jakarta`, etc.).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So what you're saying is that `slf4j` is a interface that logging frameworks like `log4j` use to log things?

Comment: Not really.  `slf4j` is a facade, but it doesn't actually do a anything on its own.  It relies on a logging implementation like `log4j2` to do the actual work of logging.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I can't really understand what is meant with facade or what it actually does. Could you perhaps make an example how a facade is used in code? 

EDIT: I still don't get it but, does `slf4j` use the logging frameworks instead of them using it? Kind of like a frontend/backend relationship?

Comment: Each logging framework has its own interface and way of doing things.  When you use `slf4j`, your code depends only on the facade.  This means that, in theory, if you launched your Java application using `Jakarta` logging (Spring), but later decided that you wanted to switch to `log4j2`, you would not have to change a single line of your Java code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So it just enables you to switch between Logging Frameworks if one becomes outdated, because you created the logging stuff with `slf4j` in your code and the actual logging happened with `log4j`?